# After submitting form values, data is not appearing in post

Tags: php

While I am sending the email on the pop up of submit button I used `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` but it does not takes the value.
 On submit button so tell me what is the problem in this code it will not accept submit as isset post.
 In the if function the of isset the submit button not inputting the values also explain if there is jquery issue

```
<?php
//print_r($_POST);die();
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
     $to = "basavraj.p@wepearl.in"; // this is your Email address
    $from = $_POST['email']; // this is the sender's Email address
    $first_name = trim($_POST['fname']);
    /*$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];*/
    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
    $phone_number = trim($_POST['phone-number']);
    $subject = trim($_POST['subject']);
    $description = trim($_POST['description']);
    $quote_sub = trim($_POST['quote-sub']);
    $message = "First Name: ".$first_name."\r\n Email: ".$email." \r\n Phone Number: ".$phone_number." \r\n Subject: ".$subject." \r\n Description: ".$description." " ;
$headers = "From: kashmira.s@wepearl.in" . "\r\n" .
    "CC: pooja.s@wepearl.in";
    /*$headers2 = "From:" . $to;*/
    if(mail($to,$quote_sub,$message,$headers))
    {       
        echo "success"; 
    }
    else
    {
        echo "failed";
        }
   }
?>
```

Comment: what is your submit button name?

Answer (score 0):

I think your query

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
```

fails because you might not have added `name="submit"` in `<input type="submit" />` statement or you may have someother name.

So, add

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go!" />
```

in your `html` page. In php, just check whether form has been submitted or not by,

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
```

To check, just echo the submitted data by,

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  $from = $_POST['email'];
  echo "From email : " . $from;

  / ..add rest here like name.../
```